# JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jackson2

My problem lies in the fields of JsonSerialization as implemented in Jackson FasterXML Library. I have a series of endpoints through which I exchange content between my back-end and a MVVM front-end framework. This is working, but now I am a little stuck as I got to the point where I want to handle user creation/registration.

This is the model (entity) that represents a group in my application (I omit irrelevant import declarations and JPA annotations):

```
@JsonRootName(value="userGroup")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Groups extends MetaInfo implements Serializable {

private String groupName;
private Set<Credential> credentials = new HashSet<>();           

public Groups() {
    super();
}

public Groups(String groupName) {
    this();
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public Groups(String createdBy, String groupName) {
    this();
    setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

@JsonGetter("group_Name")
//    @JsonValue
public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
    updateModified();
}

@JsonIgnore
public Set<Credential> getCredentials() {
    return credentials;
}

public void setCredentials(Set<Credential> credentials) {
    this.credentials = credentials;
}

public void addCredential(Credential c) {
    credentials.add(c);
    if (c.getGroup() != this) {
        c.setGroup(this);
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Groups{" + "groupName=" + groupName + '}';
}
}
```

And this is the method in the endpoint that retrieves (if exists) and returns a serialized version of a Groups to a JavaScript client:

```
@Path("/groups")
@Produces("application/json")
public class GroupsResourceService extends RimmaRestService{

@Inject
@Production
private GroupsRepository groupsRepository;

...

@GET
@Path("{group}")
public Response getGroup(@PathParam("group") String group){
    if(InputValidators.stringNotNullNorEmpty.apply(group)){
        //proceed with making call to the repo
        Optional<Groups> optGroup = ofNullable(groupsRepository.getByGroupName(group));
        if(optGroup.isPresent()){//ultimately success scenario
            try {
                String output = getMapper().writeValueAsString(optGroup.get());                    
                return Response.ok(output).build();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                logger.error("Serialization error: "+e.getMessage()+
                        "\n"+e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                throw new InternalServerErrorException("Server error "
                        + " serializing the requested group \""+group+"\"");
            }
        } else{
            throw new NotFoundException("Group " + group + " could not be found");
        }
    }else{//empty space after the slash
         throw new BadRequestException("You haven't provided a group parameter",
                    Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build());
    }
}
```

}

Trying to test this code like this:

```
@Test
public void successfullResponse(){
    Response success = groupsResourceService.getGroup("admin");
    assertTrue(success.getStatus()==200);
}
```

...cruelly fails:

```
<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: Server error  serializing the requested group "admin"
    at com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.rest.services.GroupsResourceService.getGroup(GroupsResourceService.java:54)
    at com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.services.GroupsResourceServiceTest.successfullResponse(GroupsResourceServiceTest.java:48)
```

In this case stack trace is of 0 help, though - that's why I am pasting the output of the log that catches the underlying Json exception:

```
15:05:05.857 [main] ERROR com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.rest.services.GroupsResourceService             - Serialization error: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException
```

Having visited and analyzed 13 similar complaints links (of which 3 are from stackoverflow) I came up with a solution which is more a workaround - if you look back at the entity, I have commented `@JsonValue`. If I uncomment that and comment `@JsonGetter("group_Name")` then the test passes with the following output:

```
{"userGroup":"admin"}
```

This being only a workaround, I decided to recur to asking for help which I hope someone will be able and kind enough to provide.

Comment: May I know the version of Jackson that you are currently using?

Comment: jackson{-annotations, -core, -databind, -jaxrs-base, -jaxrs-json-provider, -module-jaxb-annotations} all at 2.5.4